# Context Based Word Co-Occurrence Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, nlp

How would I be able to construct a word occurrence matrix for a document VS a set of context words?

For eg, I have a document with the following

> " Password protection is key to security "

and I have a set of context words I have derived as keywords from a set of documents to which the above document is a subset :

> " password,email, security, network .... "

Question is, how do I create a co-occurrence matrix for a non-square matrix that would have rows as document vocabulary (all the tokens) VS columns as the context words.

Goal is to find the distance between context words and the rest of the words in the document.

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: I created a numpy matrix filled with zeros. np.zeros((len(vocabs),len(context_words))). Then I created dictionary with the tokens from the document and its position as the value. For each word in the document, I check with the context words, subtract it and put its value in the matrix. However, when this happens the value goes to zero when the words are the same. This is ambiguous with the other zeros which are sparse

Comment: It's always nice to see code than a verbose description of the logic. If i remember right, nltk has an edit distance function that just does that. You may have to write your own function for your use case. Or you can use jellyfish to get different string distances like jaro-winkler and you will get ratios rather than zeroes.